# ReferenceError: document is not defined inside Next.js client component

Tags: next.js

I have a client component ("use client") created using Next.js

```
"use client"

import type { ReactPortal } from "react"
import { createPortal } from "react-dom"

interface PortalProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export function Portal(props: PortalProps): ReactPortal | null {
  return createPortal(props.children, document.body)
}
```

Whenever I visit the page which uses `<Portal />` component it throws an error in the console

```
event - compiled client and server successfully in 469 ms (1685 modules)
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Portal (webpack-internal:///(sc_client)/./src/components/portal/portal.component.tsx:9:98)
```

How can I fix that?

P.S. This is my `package.json`

```
// package.json
{
  // cut
  "next": "13.1.6"
  // cut
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found that Client components prerender on the server which doesn't have a access to the `document` object. That's why it says `document is not defined`.

There are many options how it can be fixed

1. Wrap `document` in `typeof window !== undefiend` check to make sure the document is only accessible in the browser enrironment (`window` is undefined during prerender).
2. Use `useEffect` + `useState` + `condition`

My solution to the problem looks like this

```js
"use client"

import { type ReactPortal, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { createPortal } from "react-dom"

interface PortalProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export function Portal(props: PortalProps): ReactPortal | null {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])

  return isMounted ? createPortal(props.children, document.body) : null // createPortal will not be rendered on the server. Only on the client after hydration
}
```

---

See also https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components

> Client Components
>
> Client Components enable you to add client-side interactivity to your
> application. In Next.js, they are [**prerendered**](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals#client-and-server-rendering-at-the-component-level) on the server and
> [**hydrated**](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/fundamentals#client-and-server-rendering-at-the-component-level) on the client. You can think of Client Components as how
> Next.js 12 and previous versions worked (i.e. the pages/ directory)
> See